# How to read 1TB zipped file in minimum time

Tags: bash, grep, tar, zcat

I am trying to read a zipped file. I am doing this using command `tar tf abc.tar.xz`. Because the size of the file is 1TB so it takes a lot of time. I am not much familiar with bash script. I have other commands as well such as `zcat 3532642.tar.gz | more` and `tar tf 3532642.tar.xz |grep --regex="folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/"` and

```
tar tvf 3532642.tar.xz --to-command \
'grep --label="$TAR_FILENAME" -H folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/ ; true'
```

But I dont find much difference among them in terms of time they take to execute the file to read its contents.

Does anyone know how can I do It in minimum time to process such a huge amount of data for a zipped file. Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: You won't speed unzipping, you could speed up what you are doing on the stream after. Please clearly show what are you doing with the unzipped stream.

Comment: I wan to read content of zipped file without actually unzipping it and want to do this for 1TB file. Can you tell me how can I do it in minimum time execution?

Comment: There will be no time difference in unzipping, the easiest to use is `zcat`.

Comment: You could try `pigz` for the decompress (it is multithreaded), but I suspect if you watch `top` your `tar` command is going to be at 100% cpu and will be the bottleneck.

Comment: @krzyk may you suggest me any solution for such a situation?

Comment: @rrauenza, would it be the optimal solution to use `pigz` command?

Comment: I won't commit to 'optimal', but it is potentially faster than zcat -- wait, your file is `xz` not `gz`.  `pigz` won't work.  See http://askubuntu.com/questions/258202/multi-core-compression-tools

Comment: @rrauenza If so do you have any other solution for this?

Comment: Which code warrrior downvoted this? This question is indeed an [mcve].

Comment: *I wan to read content of zipped file without actually unzipping it* shows a complete and utter fundamental lack of comprehension of what a zip file is! This is like saying I *I want to read the contents of a file on a remote server without downloading it*.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I accept my mistake but at this moment I need solution rather than pointing out such mistake. By the way I can't update my answer at this time. Moreover I already have read the contents of file. I need solution to reduce exectuion time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [`rrauenza`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2077386/rrauenza) mentions, since `pigz` may not work for the `xz` format, there is a similar tool [`pixz`](https://github.com/vasi/pixz) for parallel, indexed xz compressing/decompressing.

from the `man`  [page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pigz) it is evident that `Pigz` compresses/decommpresses using threads to make use of multiple processors and cores.

Similar to `pigz`, this command also provides an option to specify the number of threads that can be invoked in parallel in multiple cores to achieve maximum performance.

```
-p --processes n
Allow up to n processes (default is the number of online processors)
```

Or you can manually get the number of cores from the bash command `getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN` and set the value to `-p`.

More details from the `GitHub` page of [`pixz`](https://github.com/vasi/pixz) also with details on how to download and install

(or)

Going with a `tar` only solution, it can be done only if the file-name is known in prior

```
tar -zxOf <file-name_inside-tar> <file-containing-tar>
```

with options as follow:-

```
   -f, --file=ARCHIVE
          use archive file or device ARCHIV

   -z, --gzip
          filter the archive through gzip

   -x, --extract, --get
          extract files from an archive

   -O, --to-stdout
          extract files to standard output
```

May not be as effective as `pigz`, but nevertheless does the job.

Comment: But as rrauenza mentioned, it can not be used for .xz extension. Can you suggest anythig for such situation?

Comment: @MKB: Can you try the alternate solution using `tar`, if its not working too, i will remove the answer

Comment: The job is already done using `tar` but The problem is time that it takes to execute as  I've mentioned in the description of my question.

Comment: @Inian Just adapt your answer to an `xz` compatible tool from here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/258202/multi-core-compression-tools

Comment: @Inian and you probably want to recommend a `foo | tar` approach?

Comment: Does anyone have any solution?? :(

Comment: @MKB: Did you have a look the page shared for `xz` in GitHub?

Comment: Yes I have tried many things but none of them works for time optimization. Anyhow I have found another solution to do this. Now Rather than reading directly from zipped file. While creating a zipped file I'll put its folder structure into a `.txt` file. And I would read them from `.txt` file later using patterns which would be better than reading a zip file directly.

Comment: @MKB: You mean using the second approach in my answer `tar -zxOf <file-name_inside-tar> <file-containing-tar>`?

Comment: No actually I am able to read the content but wasn't able to reduce the time. Now while creating the zip file. I'll create another `.txt` file as well and then read the files and folders directly from `.txt` file rather than reading it from zipped file. But yes correct way to read a zipped file is in your mentioned answer. I am marking it correct. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @MKB: Happy if the answer helped/provided a way to solve the problem